# HTTP POST request with raw body to ORDS PL/SQL Gateway?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-ords, plsql-gateway

I am using Oracle Database 12.2 and ORDS 18.3. Is it possible to make an HTTP POST request with a raw body (no parameters using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`) to ORDS, knowing that ORDS is used only for its PL/SQL Gateway part, not the REST Data Services part.

In this scenario, ORDS in standalone mode (with Jetty) is the HTTP server. The HTTP client that makes the request is some external program (Postman, Java, ...).

The idea is to send JSON data but it could be binary data like an image or something else.

It looks like the PL/SQL Gateway is "only" able to invoke procedures using parameters (or no parameter at all but also of course no body). I am able to make a request with a dummy parameter in multipart form and somehow simulate what I want (tested with `VARCHAR2`, not `CLOB` nor `BLOB`) but I wanted to know if the possibility exists.

Comment: In the plsql gateway side, you'd probably want to do a file upload of the binary data. In the ORDS Rest side, it's just the payload is in :body bind variable

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: sure Ping me if you need an example in the rest-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, it is not possible. We have to use a parameter and the MIME type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (or `multipart/form-data`).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple [ORDS-specific bind variables (implicit parameters)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-http-headers-and-ords-specific-bind-variables) that you can use.

- `:body` will return a BLOB. This can be used for anything, including images
- `:body_text` will return a CLOB. This is useful for text bodies such as JSON, XML, or the other MIME types you indicated (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`)

NOTE: You can only dereference the `:body` or `:body_text` parameter *once* in your PL/SQL block (as indicated by [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/18.3/aelig/implicit-parameters.html#GUID-B0BB1694-715C-4948-84A5-307EA3868063)), so you may need to assign it to a local variable before using it.

Comment: Yes indeed, but with RESTful web services not with the PL/SQL gateway only. This is why I wrote "knowing that ORDS is used only for its PL/SQL Gateway part, not the REST Data Services part.".